# Trying to model a pen and can't seem to be able to model the shape correctly

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So I have been trying to model this pen (from the tip to line were you unscrew the pen aka the line to the right of the pen in the first pic), but have no idea how to accurately get the sort of bevel and smooth effect on the corners of the pen. Each face of the pen also slightly goes out. The faces arent flat surfaces, but actually sort of curve around slightly.

[image: Pen Sideview]

Another angle:
[image]

The Shape:
[image]

How would you go about modeling this. I've tried using a cone with subdivision surfaces, but the corners were still to sharp, and when I turned the smoothness up to a point were the shape looked similar, the middle bloated outwards.

[image]

Does anyone know what tools/modifiers/shapes I would use to get this sort of effect. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a 3 vertex circle:

[image]

Bevel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (to switch from edge bevel to vertex bevel, press <kbd>V</kbd> or click on *Vertex* in the *Operator* box):

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, move the vertices a bit so that it matches as much possible with the profile (actually select 2 vertices and scale to adapt the shape, and again):

[image]

Extrude up and scale a bit as it looks like it's getting thiner:

[image]

Extrude again and right click > *LoopTools > Circle* (activate the *LoopTools* addon if necessary) to get a perfect circle at the end:

[image]

Extrude again, add some edge loops:

[image]

Comment: how do you smooth out the edge loops?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? I've described the process in detail, it should work, if you're talking about the shading: right click > Shade Smooth

Comment: @Sparkylc2, also give your object a Subdivision Surface modifier

Comment: I have but i still get the sort of lines even after i shade smooth. Im kinda new so im still figuring things out

Comment: it may be because you have inverted normals, try to recalculate normals in Edit mode (select all and Shift N), or please share your file (upload and copy paste the url here): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: before you judge my editing, i added way to many subdivisions and i did it and just wasnt bothered to go back which has now kicked me in the ass

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/9aa5215811de4d39bb4c6cfec8313b5e

Comment: also as i said im new so i probably didnt do it right, but I did read it all and tried so i really do appreciate your help!

Comment: You've subdivided too much, and if the profile is not good, more subdivision won't improve anything, it will just sharpen the edges, you need to go back to a very simple topology like the one I show

Comment: And anyway don't apply any Subdivision Surface modifier unless you really need to do it for some reason, plus you don't have a very high level of subdivision in the modifier, 1 or 2 or OK most of the times

Comment: okay, one last question, at the start you said to bevel the 3 sided circle, however when I do that I just get a glitchy mess. can you explain it in slightly more detail. I know its a simple task but

Comment: select the 3 vertex mesh in Edit mode and Ctrl B to bevel, then while you drag your mouse press V to switch to vertex bevel if it's not already the case, then you can play with the parameters in the Operator box if necessary (the box on the bottom left of your 3D view), like Widht and Segments

Comment: also what do you mean by select 2 vertices and scale and adapt them? Wouldnt you just move 1 at a time and not scale?

Comment: select 2 opposite vertices and scale so that the change is symmetrical, it's better and faster than just moving one vertex